# Is there a word for a great price paid in exchange for a great gain?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

For example, let’s say that, in return for a Ph.D., the hero had to give up ten years of life. I’d thought of calling that a *blood price* but maybe there’s a better word? Seems like maybe some Saxons or Picts would have worked some quite dramatic tradeoffs into their folklore – so, just like Irish folklore gave us the wonderful word *geas*, maybe there’s a short, non-Latin word for a … (substitute in for *blood price*) … .

Answer (score 8):

The term **sacrifice** is used to convey the giving of something important. Originally used to refer to gifts to gods, it is now used in any context of a great giving, usually for a highly valued gain.

Comment: Absolutely. Leading to [supreme sacrifice](http://www.yourdictionary.com/supreme-sacrifice), which I think always and unambiguously means *the sacrifice of one's life*.

Comment: +1, good suggestion. I'm not sure how much it matters to the OP, but the word *sacrifice* does come from Latin.

Answer (score 1):

How about *Pyrrhic*?  It doesn't have an implication of necessarily great gain, but the great cost is there.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhic_victory):

> A Pyrrhic victory (/ˈpɪrɪk/) is a victory with such a devastating cost
>   that it carries the implication that another such victory will
>   ultimately lead to defeat.